# How to set lock_timeout for transaction in snowflake through connection string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timeout, locking

I am connecting snowflake via .net application, but currently my transaction are getting locked and default timeout for transaction locks are 12 hours can I set it to 5 mins through connection string

I updated the connection string to have one more parameter as Lock_timeout = {value}

Answer (score 0):

That’s not a valid connection property (as defined here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net#create-a-connection). You would need to explicitly set it in your code, having established the connection, or, if appropriate, set it for the user that is using the connection

Comment: Any suggestions how we can setup at the code level.

Comment: Issue the SQL command SET LOCK_TIMEOUT = 300